# Combine elements of a cell into a matrix

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a cell (called AA ) that contains **1 row * 36 columns** (as shown in the attached image)

[image: AA Cell]

As we could see that each **column** in that cell is a matrix (  inside each column there are 1*3 data points )

I need to have an array that has **36 Rows * 3 columns** in MATLAB

**For example**,

the first column in the Cell will be converted into **1 Row and three columns**,  the second column in the Cell will be converted in the same way and **finally** put them all of them together in order to generate an array that contains **36 Rows and 3 Columns**

**as shown in this example**

```
-1.48247427405830e-15   0.185513882360673   -0.185513882360676

-9.59200039657764e-16   0.211729497802758   -0.211729497802760

3.69087930153418e-16    0.224791092084074   -0.224791092084073
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) to concatenate the rows and use `{:}` indexing to create a [comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)

```
output = cat(1, AA{:})
```

Comment: you are helpful guy, perfect answer and simple. thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @Neamah `vertcat` essentially an alias for `cat(1, ...)`

Comment: Yeah dear i wrote that in my post as well, please see my previous post

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of the gentleman Suever these are 2 methods as well  that can be used to solve the same question

```
output =cell2mat(AA(:))
```

or, more simply,

```
   output = vertcat(AA{:})
```